# Resource Request- Good classifcation of shapes by number of vertices?

Tags: soft-question

There are many websites that classify various aspects of mathematics.

For example:

- [Integral table](http://integral-table.com/), a huge list of integrals
- oeis.org/
- www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Main_Page
- en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Mathematics-related_lists

However, I am unable to find a classification of shapes by vertices.  Does anyone know of one I have missed searching online for?

Comment: What is your definition of "shape"?

Comment: I was thinking for circles, squares, etc; but if you have another definition of shape and a resource that goes with it, I would like to know about it.

Comment: My point is, the classification very strongly depends on what you mean by "shape" in the first place, and under what circumstances you consider two shapes the same. Even counting similar triangles as the same, for example, there are infinite many kinds of triangles.

Comment: @Travis but every triangle only has three vertices.  I am asking for objects which have the same number of vertices, as list of those.

Comment: Of course, you can classify polygons by number of vertices just by, well, counting their vertices. But circles, for example, do not have vertices.